# Simple RewriteRule causing problems

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We want this type of URL: www.ourdomain.com/dev/kunde-first/service

to be rewritten to: www.ourdomain.com/dev/kunde-first/inhalt.php?id=service

and are using this in our .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dev/kunde-first/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|txt|html|htm|xml|eot|woff|ttf|svg)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.(scripts/[^/]*)$

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+) inhalt.php?id=$1 [NC,L] # process navigation
```

However, when we fetch $_GET['id'] we get 'inhalt' instead of 'service'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule with correct regex:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dev/kunde-first/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ inhalt.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```